# Angular, detect which element the current screen is sliding on

Tags: angular

Angular `@HostListener` can detect mouse movement.But I want to be able to identify the interval of the element where I ’m sliding.

For example:

Component:

```
 @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) 
      onScroll(event) {
      console.log(event);
      //When the mouse is scrolled, identify which element is currently displayed on the browser window, A or B or C
      //element A,B,C height is not fixed
      }
```

css:

```
#a,#b,#c {
 width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="a" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    Block A
      .
      .
      (more element)
    </div>
    <div id="b" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    Block B
      .
      .
      (more element)
    </div>
    <div id="c" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    Block C
      .
      .
      (more element)
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried to look at the `event` parameter, but it is a fairly large object and I cannot find the difference between the different elements:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**event.target** object should contain all you need to distinguish those blocks since it is  **is a reference to the object that dispatched the event**

```
console.log(event.target.id) // a, b or c
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/BSttKRWB0cBuw7vmQhuR)**

### Update

In order to identify which full height div block is currently displayed you can just do some math like:

```
areas = ['a', 'b', 'c']

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
  const activeElem = this.areas[
      Math.floor(window.pageYOffset/ document.documentElement.clientHeight)
  ];
  console.log(activeElem);
}
```

Note that you do not need to add event handler to your block:

```
<div id="..." (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              remove this
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/n2RTGJk3hiijMlhulEFX)**

### Update 2

If height of section is not fixed then you can get reference to all your sections by using ViewChildren:

**html**

```
<div #a

<div #b

<div #c
```

**ts**

```
const areas = 'a,b,c';

class Component {
    @ViewChildren(areas) sections: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

and then check if specific section is inside viewport by using some helper like:

```
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (
    rect.bottom >= 0 &&
    rect.right >= 0 &&
    rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
  const activeSection = this.sections.toArray()
     .findIndex(section => isElementInViewport(section.nativeElement));

  console.log(areas.split(',')[activeSection]);
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/yP0y7za0BJW0pMlOPdAt)**

Comment: Please check out the demo I linked

Comment: oh.. sorry, I may have misunderstood the function of scroll. I want to detect the position of the element in the `<body>` when the mouse is swiped, not that the element is swiped. I will modify my example.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my case that seems to have caused misunderstanding again.., the height of the element is not fixed, so the current position cannot be determined by calculating the height of the screen. I will modify my case again.